# CSS Background not clickable - a href="" not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have the following code that produces a logo the logo shows its in the correct place but the `a href=""` is not working why?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="banner">
    <span><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL()?>link" title="View information about award"></a></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.banner{
            width:592px;
            height:1px;
            position: fixed;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            overflow: visible;
        }
        div.banner span{
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: url(../../../i/ribbon.png) top right no-repeat;
            width: 197px;
            height: 145px;
            text-indent: -999em;
        }
        div.opens span a{
            display:block;
            width: 197px;
            height: 145px;
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn`t it be `div.banner span a` instead of `div.opens span a`?

Comment: something more descriptive than "It's not working" would be nice

Comment: what do you mean with link ?

Comment: the `text-indent` would be moving the link off the edge of the screen

Comment: Why not make the whole div a link? (you can just write .banner - no need for div.banner ) and there is no mention of your .open in the html...  You height is set to 1px... why is this? that isn't much to click on... uh... I think we can be safe in assumeing that when they say a link isn't working... it means that when they click on it, it doesn't work... as in - the link doesn't function because it's covered up by another div / out of the flow, etc... text indented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link class should be `div.banner span a` instead of `div.opens span a`. So your link has no text and because of that no width as the CSS rule doesn't apply. So there's nothing to click on.

Comment: Thanks :) I need another set of eyes

Answer (score 0):

probably you need something like this

```
<div class="banner">
    <span>
          <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL().'/thisFile.html'; ?>" title="View information about award">
          This is the link to the file
          </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ZygsF/)

I guess, I can't tell you why your code isn't working specifically, but I see a few things it could be... This is how I would approach it. If you make the whole banner the link, then it's easier to click then some text that is -999em's off the page?

You don't really need a possitioning wrapper, but for the sake of keeping things modular, it could help you to use these banner classes over and over again in different contexts.

If I am WAY off the question, let me know and I'll try to steer back around.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-wrapper">

    <a class="banner" href="#">

        Some words for robots and for assistive text ?          

        <span class="open">a different image I'm assuming?</span>

    </a> <!-- end .banner -->

</div> <!-- end .fixed-wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
.fixed-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:592px;
    height:145px;

    background-color: #f06;
}

.banner {
    text-indent: -999em;
}

.open {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 197px;
    height: 145px;

    background-color: orange;
}

.banner:hover .open {    
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* i assume that your .open does something... */
```

[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ZygsF/)